# Copy DVD to iTunes for watching on Apple TV

Tags: itunes, appletv

I have quite a collection of DVDs which is slowly getting smaller and smaller thanks (in part) to crappy Wal-Mart binder style DVD cases scratching the discs.  After purchasing an Apple TV, I'm wondering if it is possible to backup DVD's so that they can be watched in iTunes, and subsequently on my Apple TV.  I'm running OSX.6, if this helps any.

I would prefer FOSS, but I wouldn't mind paying for something that works, and will be around for a while.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use [Handbrake](http://handbrake.fr/) for this.

Comment: I second this. I use Handbrake for all my DVD ripping and media conversion.

Comment: I'll third this.  Handbrake is great because it has Apple TV settings built in that you can rip to. (Also has settings for iPhone)

Comment: I've had better luck using an updated nightly build than the released version. YMMV https://build.handbrake.fr/

Answer (score 6):

I highly recommend having this app in your arsenal for pesky discs that won't rip.

**RipIt**: http://thelittleappfactory.com/ripit/

> RipIt is guaranteed to work and has a 99.9999% success rate in ripping DVDs. In fact, it has been verified to work with over 250,000 unique discs, and is continuously updated to rip the latest releases.

I would also like to mention that I own this software and I was recently unable to rip the movie "Kick-Ass". I contacted customer support with my issue, and later that day they sent me a link to download an updated beta version of the app with a fix for my disc. It doesn't get much better than that!

Answer (score 3):

Handbrake was unsuccessful at ripping the first 3 DVDs I tried, but I found an older program called [MacTheRipper](http://www.macupdate.com/info.php/id/14414/mactheripper) that works great for ripping.  Then I throw the ripped video files at Handbrake for encoding.

Comment: make sure you also have VLC installed in your /Applications folder or Handbrake won't be able to rip DVDs.

Comment: I do have VLC there, and it didn't seem like a problem caused by  an application being in the wrong place.  Handbrake would rip part of the disc (between "a few hundred KB" and "almost all of it", depending on the disc) and then just stop, 100% of the time.  This problem is in the Handbrake FAQ, and it says something like "if you have a slow machine like a G4, just wait a bit longer, it's *fine*", but I've let it run 24 hours on my Core 2 Duo with no progress, and MacTheRipper finishes in a matter of minutes.

Answer (score 1):

I use [Aimersoft DVD Ripper](http://www.aimersoft.com/dvd-ripper.html) (PC) and have had great experiences.

It's not free, but it's simple and very easy to use. It's even got useful presets:

[image]

It's also got GPU hardware acceleration which makes the ripping process faster and smoother. I used an old dual-core Atom-powered Shuttle PC, however, to rip my entire DVD collection and it worked great.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [VLC](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/download-macosx.html) media player, VLC is FOSS as you requested.

Please refer to the following post:
https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/105382/10733

Answer (score 0):

I tested the latest version of VLC media player (2.2.2), and it seems that VLC works well on DVDs released before 2014 - but can't process the DVDs of the last year or two. Plus, If you have any problems, I highly recommend visiting [DVD0101.com](http://dvd0101.com), which offers various tools and tips and tricks related to DVD digitization.