# How can I convert an m4a to mov?

Tags: file-conversion, m4a, mov

I have a m4a audio file that I need to convert to a mov file. How can I do this?

Comment: mov is a video format, what exactly do you want to convert here?

Comment: Exactly what I said. I have a m4a file that I want to make into a video file. Is there a tool that makes this easy? I suppose the video portion would be just a black image, but if the tool allows me to select what image is displayed while the audio plays, that would be better.

Comment: Just out of curiosity: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: I'm doing it to upload my podcast audio file to YouTube to take advantage of auto-captioning for a deaf colleague who wants to subscribe.

Answer (score 8):

This creates an x264-encoded mov file with image.png as the background:

`ffmpeg -loop 1 -i image.png -i audio.m4a -c:a copy -c:v libx264 -crf 20 -pix_fmt yuv420p -shortest output.mov`

You can use mp4 or mkv as the container by just changing the name of the output file.

`-c:a copy` disables re-encoding the audio.

`-loop 1` loops the image infinitely so that it is not shown for just one frame. It also makes the video stream infinitely long, so `-shortest` is needed to finish encoding after the audio stream finishes. `-shortest` has to be after the input files in new versions of ffmpeg.

`-crf` (constant rate factor) can be from 0 (lossless) to 51 (lowest quality). If you remove `-pix_fmt yuv420p`, ffmpeg uses yuv444p, which is not supported by many video players.

You can use a black background by replacing `-loop 1 -i image.png` with `-f lavfi -i color=c=black:s=1280x720`. You can resize an image by adding an option like `-filter:v '[in] scale=-1:720, pad=1280:720:640-iw/2 [out]'`.

More information:

- https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/EncodeforYouTube
- https://superuser.com/questions/98980
- http://tdb0.wordpress.com/2012/03/10/how-to-upload-a-song-without-a-music-video-to-youtube/

Answer (score 0):

Open the .m4a in QuickTime and export it as a .mov file.

Comment: Doesn't work. The Format menu only provides the option "Audio Only". I want an actual movie...I suppose the video portion would be just a black image.

Answer (score 0):

You could use iMovie to create a movie just showing a black screen and using the audio file as the audio track.

Comment: Good idea. Any good set of instructions for how to do that?

Answer (score -1):

This can be accomplished with VLC.

Please refer to the following transcoding [instructions](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/105382/10733).

Answer (score -1):

Flip for Mac easily opened, converted and saved the file to .MOV